# Why does JavaScript map function return undefined?

Tags: javascript

My code

```
 var arr = ['a','b',1];
 var results = arr.map(function(item){
                if(typeof item ==='string'){return item;}  
               });
```

This gives the following results

```
["a","b",undefined]
```

I don't want `undefined` in the results array. How can I do it?

Comment: Because you don't return anything unless it's a string. Therefore, the last item returns `undefined`. What do you expect to return if it's not a string? An empty string?

Comment: @BenM if it is not a string I want nothing returned.Not even undefined.

Comment: Looks like I was using the wrong method to do this.I will use filter as suggested.

Comment: jQuery.map is actually smart enough to not include undefined and null values in the resulting array.

Comment: @JackB Ahh that is a nice find.I will check out how they do it in their source code.Thanks

Comment: @DonaldTaylor In this case though it's more clear to use the filter method to what you want to do, filter out elements, not map one value to another.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

You aren't returning anything in the case that the item is not a string. In that case, the function returns `undefined`, what you are seeing in the result.

The map function is used to map one value to another, but it looks like you actually want to filter the array, which a map function is not suitable for.

What you actually want is a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. It takes a function that  returns true or false based on whether you want the item in the resulting array or not.

```
var arr = ['a','b',1];
var results = arr.filter(function(item){
    return typeof item ==='string';  
});
```

Comment: This makes quite a bit of sense. I was not .map'ing I was .filter'ing... How did you know?! O.o Thanks ^.^

Answer (score 54):

Filter works for this specific case where the items are not modified. **But in many cases when you use map you want to make some modification to the items passed.**

if that is your intent, you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var arr = ['a','b',1];
var results = arr.reduce((results, item) => {
    if (typeof item === 'string') results.push(modify(item)) // modify is a fictitious function that would apply some change to the items in the array
    return results
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks - `map` results in arrays with `undefined`. `filter` only returns the item or not. this is perfect

Answer (score 21):

Since ES6 `filter` supports pointy arrow notation (like LINQ):

So it can be boiled down to following one-liner.

```
['a','b',1].filter(item => typeof item ==='string');
```

Answer (score 21):

You can implement like a below logic.
Suppose you want an array of values.

```
let test = [ {name:'test',lastname:'kumar',age:30},
             {name:'test',lastname:'kumar',age:30},
             {name:'test3',lastname:'kumar',age:47},
             {name:'test',lastname:'kumar',age:28},
             {name:'test4',lastname:'kumar',age:30},
             {name:'test',lastname:'kumar',age:29}]

let result1 = test.map(element => 
              { 
                 if (element.age === 30) 
                 {
                    return element.lastname;
                 }
              }).filter(notUndefined => notUndefined !== undefined);

output : ['kumar','kumar','kumar']
```

Answer (score 20):

My solution would be to use filter after the map.

This should support every JS data type.

example:

```
const notUndefined = anyValue => typeof anyValue !== 'undefined'    
const noUndefinedList = someList
          .map(// mapping condition)
          .filter(notUndefined); // by doing this, 
                      //you can ensure what's returned is not undefined
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have to use map to return custom output, you can still combine it with filter.

```
const arr = ['a','b',1]

const result = arr.map(element => {

  if(typeof element === 'string')
    return element + ' something'

}).filter(Boolean) // this will filter out null and undefined

console.log(result) // output: ['a something', 'b something']
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know you can use `filter` like this. So, `Array.map` will always return an array with the same number of items as the original array, and `Array.filter` will not?

Comment: `.filter(Boolean)` ooooh yes.

Answer (score 9):

You only return a value if the current element is a `string`. Perhaps assigning an empty string otherwise will suffice:

```
var arr = ['a','b',1];
var results = arr.map(function(item){
    return (typeof item ==='string') ? item : '';  
});
```

Of course, if you want to filter any non-string elements, you shouldn't use `map()`. Rather, you should look into using the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Comment: This returns an empty string if there exists an number

Answer (score 6):

```
var arr = ['a','b',1];
var results = arr.filter(function(item){
                if (typeof item ==='string') {return item;}  
               });
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into this quite frequently where the type after filtering will still be `string | number`. So, to expand upon these solutions and include type safety you can use a user-defined type guard.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

```
const result = ['a','b',1].filter((item) => typeof item ==='string');
// result is typed as (string | number)[]
```

Better type safety using user-defined type guard

```
const result = ['a','b',1].filter((item): item is string => typeof item ==='string');
// result is now typed as string[]
```

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**
the issue is `arr.map()` will do a full iteration of `arr` array length, i.e. `map()` method will loop as much as the length of `arr` is, no matter what condition you have inside it, so if you defined a condition inside it e.g.  `if(typeof item ==='string'){return item;}` even if the condition is not happening, the `map()` will be forced to keep looping until finishing the looping of the whole `arr` so it will give you `undefined` for the rest of elements if the condition is not met.

**The solutions:**

**Solution One:** if you want to return the whole item in the array when the condition is met, you can use `arr.filter()` so the filter will return the whole item for the iteration e.g. if you have array of objects like bellow

```js
const arr = [{name: "Name1", age: 25}, {name: "Name2", age: 30}, {name: "Name3", age: 25}]
```

and you want to return the whole objects when the condition is met like example below

```js
const filteredItems = arr.filter((item)=>{if(item.age === 25){return true}})

console.log(filteredItems) //results: [{name: "Name1", age: 25}, {name: "Name3", age: 25}]
```

conclusion: *`filter()` method returns an array of the whole items in it if the condition is met.*

**Solution Two:** if you want to return only a specific data of the objects (or the whole object or any shape of data) in array i.e. if you want to return only the names in array without the ages, you can do this

```js
const namesOnly = arr.map((item)=>{if(item.age === 25){return item.name}})

console.log(namesOnly) //results: ["Name1, udefined, "Name3"]
```

now to remove the `undefined` you just use `filter()` method on the results like below

```js
const namesOnly = arr.map((item)=>{if(item.age === 25){return item.name}}).filter((item)=> !!item)

console.log(namesOnly) //results: ["Name1, "Name3"]
```

conclusion: *`map()` method returns an array of specifically defined data in the return, and returns `undefined` if the condition is not met. so then we can use `filter()` method to remove the `undefined`.*

Answer (score 0):

If you use it like this, your problem will be solved.
Also, you will have a clean and short code

```
var _ = require('lodash'); //but first, npm i lodash --save
var arr = ['a','b',1];
var results = _.compact(
    _.map(arr, function(item){
        if(_.isString(item)){return item;}
    }
); //false, null, undefined ... etc will not be included
```

with ES6...

```
const _ = require('lodash'); //but first, npm i lodash --save
const arr = ['a','b',1];
const results = _.compact(
    _.map(arr, item => {
        if(_.isString(item)){return item;}
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter records with `.map` easily using below example code

```
const datapoints = [
    {
        PL_STATUS: 'Packetloss',
        inner_outerx: 'INNER',
        KPI_PL: '97.9619'
    },
    {
        PL_STATUS: 'Packetloss',
        inner_outerx: 'OUTER',
        KPI_PL: '98.4621',
    },
    {
        PL_STATUS: 'Packetloss',
        inner_outerx: 'INNER',
        KPI_PL: '97.8770',
    },
    {
        PL_STATUS: 'Packetloss',
        inner_outerx: 'OUTER',
        KPI_PL: '97.5674',

    },
    {
        PL_STATUS: 'Packetloss',
        inner_outerx: 'INNER',
        KPI_PL: '98.7150',
    },
    {
        PL_STATUS: 'Packetloss',
        inner_outerx: 'OUTER',
        KPI_PL: '98.8969'
    }
];
const kpi_packetloss_inner: string[] = [];
datapoints.map((item: { PL_STATUS: string; inner_outerx: string; KPI_PL: string }) => {
    if (item.PL_STATUS === 'Packetloss' && item.inner_outerx === 'INNER') {
        kpi_packetloss_inner.push(item.KPI_PL);
    }
})
console.log(kpi_packetloss_inner);
```

Comment: This question is asked more than 9 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate of another question, so that's why I added my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Map is used when you want to produced new modified array from the original array.
the simple answer may be for someone

```
      var arr = ['a','b',1];
      var results = arr.filter(function(item){
      // Modify your original array here
     return typeof item ==='string';  
     }).filter(a => a);
```

Comment: Is that not just a copy of a 9 years old upvoted answer? If not, please consider adding some explanation on how it is different, and how it is better than existing answers.