# how is undefined treated while looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 5, undefined, 4, 3, 4].map((item) => {
    if (item) {
        return item
    }
})
```

The output of the above code is

[image]

Why is `undefined` also returned, shouldn't it be stopped by the `if` loop?

Comment: You're probably looking for `filter` because `map` return the same size like the original array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing undefined values from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607451/removing-undefined-values-from-array) (or [How to remove undefined and create a new array Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749528/how-to-remove-undefined-and-create-a-new-array-javascript), or [Why does javascript map function return undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037049/why-does-javascript-map-function-return-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map function doesn't return anything explicitly if the item is falsy, hence it returns `undefined` (per default).

As another comment has pointed out, you are probably looking for [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
console.log([1,3,4,5,5,undefined,4,3,4].filter((item)=>{
  if(item){
    return item;
  }
}));
```

Note that the above is slightly verbose, `.filter(x => x)` would suffice, `filter` calls `ToBoolean` on the return anyways. It will still filter out any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values though, e.g. 0.